# Sproutcore - rails - Many-to-many - json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, associations, sproutcore

Consider two models in rails ModelA and ModelB, with their counterparts in Sproutcore. Suppose that we have a many-to-many relationship between the two models.

So, in `ModelA`, we have an attribute `bArray`, which contains references to `ModelB` objects. And in `ModelB`, we have an attribute `aArray`, which contains references to `ModelA` objects.

What I'd like to know is when you are writing the `as_json()` method to serve data from rails to sproutcore, would you include the `bArray` and `aArray` objects directly, or just take the `bArray_ids` and `aArray_ids`.

The reason I am asking the question is that including `aArray` and `bArray` copy `ModelA` and `ModelB` objects, instead of just taking the id. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Please make your question look a bit better. One big blob of text is not nice to read.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the ids. If for no other reason, a small transfer size. Sproutcore will model either structure, so I would just keep it simple.

When you load ModelA into the DataStore with ModelB references and vice versa, the DataStore will keep the most recent record with the corresponding id. So you would be wasting time nesting the records.